# Retrieving data from a table with user defined column type in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a table report. It has a column NAME which has a user-defined datatype.

I want to retrieve that data from the database using the JDBC API.
Stack Overflow already has the same question but that is for PLSQL procedure with the user-defined data type.

In my case I am using result set to get the output, but don't know exactly how to do it. How can I get the data from user defined column type?

I tried using STRUCT but can do it.

I wrote this code after doing some research.

```
while (orset.next()) {
            System.out.println("inside first for loop");
            Object data = (Object) ((Array) orset.getObject("Parameter")).getArray();
            Struct row = (Struct) data;
            // Attributes are index 1 based...
            int idx = 1;
            for (Object attribute : row.getAttributes()) {
                System.out.println("inside 2nd for loop");
                System.out.println(idx + " -- " + attribute);
                ++idx;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the custom data type and save it to database:

[How to Serialize objects in java exampe](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/HowtoserializedeserializeaJavaobjecttotheMySQLdatabase.htm)

Also you can get hint/ help from
[How to Serialize object in Java - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901706/how-to-save-a-serialized-object-in-a-database)